# PHP - create multidimensional array inside function

Tags: php, arrays, function, return

I want to create multidimensional array inside function and then access it outside function. Right now I have this function:

```
function custom_shop_array_create($product, $counter){
    $product_id = get_the_ID();
    $product_title = get_the_title($product_id);
    $products_arr[]['id'] = $product_id;
    $products_arr[]['title'] = $product_title;
    $products_arr[]['price'] = $product->get_price();
    $products_arr[]['image'] = get_the_post_thumbnail($product_id, 'product-list-thumb', array('class' => 'product-thumbnail', 'title' => $product_title));
    return $products_arr;
}
```

and it is called inside this code:

```
$products_arr = array();
    if ( $products->have_posts() ) : while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post();
        custom_shop_array_create($product);
    endwhile;
    endif;
```

the problem is that I cant access `$products_arr`. I have tried replacing `custom_shop_array_create($product);` with `$my_array[] = custom_shop_array_create($product);` but then I get 3 dimensional array. So is there any way to get 2 dimensional array that would look like this:

```
product 1 (id,title,price,image)
product 2 (id,title,price,image) etc.
```

outside of the function.

Thanks in forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Make your function return a *row* of the final array and do the appending yourself:

```
function custom_shop_array_create($product, $counter){
    $product_id = get_the_ID();
    $product_title = get_the_title($product_id);
    return [
        'id' => $product_id,
        'title' => $product_title,
        // etc
    ];
}
```

And then:

```
$products_arr = array();
if ( $products->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $products->have_posts() ) : 
        $products->the_post();
        $products_arr[] = custom_shop_array_create($product);
    endwhile;
endif;
```

That said, something strange is going on in the `while` loop. What does `$products->the_post()` do? Where is `$product` coming from?

Comment: it is comming from woocommerce plugin. It is eshop and product is some sort of global variable. I havent dug in their code so I dont know where exactly doest it come from but it is working so thats enough for me :)

Comment: are you sure that return should look like yours return? Because dreamweaver is saying that there is syntax error in return statement.

Comment: @horin: That is PHP 5.4 array syntax, you can replace `[ ... ]` with `array( ... )` if it bothers you. BTW, Dreamweaver is -- let's say not the best tool to write code with.

Comment: yes I have replaced it with array(). Probably my server doesnt support PHP 5.4. I have one side question: which tool do you use to write code because I doesnt like dreamweaver too but I dont know about any other good tool

Comment: @horin: Dreamweaver does not understand the syntax. Your server might very well support it. I use PhpStorm for large-scale work and Sublime Text for the small stuff.